# RC circuit for EDM machine pulsing backwards

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, resistors, circuit-design, pulse

I am building a hackaday EDM machine project. Same as picture attached minus the 3D printer board and with a 120 V, 9 Ω setup instead.

I measured my voltages with a multimeter and across my electrodes and most other spots on the wiring I am at 120 V, but it's only pulsing 0-100 V (as it should at 10 kHz) between the power supply side of the resistor array and the negative. Completely backwards to me. I am new to this to be honest so the answer may be simple. Sorry for the mess as I am trying to set it up while printing a box with fans etc.

[image]

[image]

Best diagram I could find not super accurate because I changed some things but I don't know how to make a proper one.
[image]

Comment: Welcome! Can you please provide the circuit in schematic form if a schematic is available? While a wiring diagram is helpful for wiring and assembly, it makes it difficult to coherently analyze the circuit since it focuses on the wiring needs rather than the actual circuit design.

Comment: I added the best "schematic" I have. I am not really sure how to make one. Thanks.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to feed 60V into the 12V regulator as it is probably not rated for such a high input voltage.

Comment: It's 12V from a separate PSU on the MOSFET driver. That part is only touching the gate of the irfp260.

Answer (score 1):

When the Arduino output is high, M1 is 'on' and M2 is 'off', meaning no current flows through the load + resistors. That is as it should be.

I hope you don't actually have R7 = 10kΩ- that would be very high for 10kHz switching of a beefy MOSFET like the IRFP260 with >200 nC of gate charge.

Comment: What resistor should I be using instead? It seems to be that it's pulsing very slow like fading when I check with my multimeter. I did rearrange the ground wire from the capacitor to the irfp260 and I got the 0-100v pulse on my electrode and workpiece but still my resistors get too hot and I cant get it to behave as it should so I am thinking it's a frequency issue

Comment: A gate driver chip would be much better (and would get rid of the inversion). If you must use a resistor, maybe 100Ω/2W. It will get quite hot when the PWM is off.

Comment: I got a 100ohm resistor and it does get hot but not that much. I am still not sure whats wrong, i just bought a cheap osciloscope to find out if theres any PWM from the arduino or the irf520 or the irfp260 because i am a bit lost. My other option i was thinking but not sure, is if i would get a motor pwm controller and measure frequency somehow and use that to generate my signal.